# Remove elements of list based on condition during "loop"

Tags: r, lapply

I'm dealing with a very large list of large data frames (~2GB).  To save space and reduce file size, I want to remove some elements of the list that are all `NA`.  As part of the operation I need to `gather` and then bind into a single data.frame.

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(x=rep(1,3), y1=1:3, y2=1:3)
b <- data.frame(x=rep(2,3), y1=NA,  y2=NA)
c <- data.frame(x=rep(3,3), y1=1:3, y2=NA)

l <- list(a,b,c)

t <- lapply(l, function(x){
  gather(x, key="type", value="value", -x) # %>%
    #remove list element here %>%
    #do other operations like mutate here
}) %>%
  bind_rows
```

The result of this includes some data.frames that are all `NA` for my values of `y`.

I would like to remove elements from the list completely.  If remove all rows with `NA` it still leaves me with an empty list element, which then crashes further calculations with `mutate` or other operations.

I'm trying to take care of this operation with the first call to `lapply` because I find that doing filtering after that requires a lot of memory (often crashing after maxing out the 16GB I have on this computer). In the title when I say "list" I'm referring to this `apply` statement.

In this example the result should look like:

```
> t[-(7:12),]
   x type value
1  1   y1     1
2  1   y1     2
3  1   y1     3
4  1   y2     1
5  1   y2     2
6  1   y2     3
13 3   y1     1
14 3   y1     2
15 3   y1     3
16 3   y2    NA
17 3   y2    NA
18 3   y2    NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not 100% sure I understood the question, but assuming I did, a possible answer would be:

```
t <- lapply(l, function(x){ 
           gather(x, key="type", value="value", -x) %>%    
                  subset(!sum(!is.na(value)) == 0) }) 
        %>% bind_rows
t
   x type value
1  1   y1     1
2  1   y1     2
3  1   y1     3
4  1   y2     1
5  1   y2     2
6  1   y2     3
7  3   y1     1
8  3   y1     2
9  3   y1     3
10 3   y2    NA
11 3   y2    NA
12 3   y2    NA
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid create separate variable, i.e. doing as much as I can with pipes. If I create separate variables I run out of memory.  Can I bring the `subset` statement inside the `lapply` statement and use pipes?

Comment: @LloydChristmas with the example you provided, you can! In general, I don't see why you wouldn't, given that the output from `subset` is a list itself.

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to work.  Although it results in a nested `lapply` statement.  I will test this on my larger dataset and see if it is computationally viable.  Revised code: `lapply(l, function(x){
   gather(x, key="type", value="value", -x)  %>%
   subset(unlist(lapply(l, function(x) !all(is.na(x[,-1])))))}) %>%
  bind_rows`

Comment: With the revised code you provided at don't get the same results. I get the right results, if I first use `gather` to get `t` and then subset it.

Comment: You're right.  This greatly simplified code works well.  If you update answer to reflect it I will accept. `lapply(l, function(x){ 
  gather(x, key="type", value="value", -x) %>% 
      subset(!sum(!is.na(value)) == 0)
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows`